# What purpose does the enum name serve?

Tags: c, enums

- An enum is a "named collection of constants":  `enum MyType_e {A, B, C};`
- Those constants are declared in the parent scope of the enum i.e. if the enum is declared in file scope, and is unnamed, it is equivalent to a series of e.g.`#define A 0` statements
- The underlying type for enum constants is always `int` i.e. `int var = A` is fully legal, although `var` is not of type `MyType_e`

So what purpose does the enum **name** serve?

**EDIT**
As per the comments below, my understanding of enums appears to be quite flawed. **An enum has nothing to do with #define statements.** [Enums are resolved at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16100283/1145760), and are typed.

Comment: Can you point to sections of the C standard where you're getting these ideas from? C doesn't have namespaces (at least in the sense that I think you're referring to here), and nor is the underlying type for enums always int. Or is this from a newer C standard?

Comment: @Anonymous: 6.7.2.2/3 of the C99 standard says "The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type `int`...".  This is kind of confusing, though, since it later goes on to say, "Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type.  The choice of type is implementation-defined...." So the constants themselves are `int`, but the `enum` type itself might not be.  By "namespace", I think Vorac meant "scope".

Comment: @jamesdlin, Anonymous: I modified the question to be less incorrect. The implementation-dependant type for enums is news for me. Quite interesting.

Comment: "These constants... parent scope... and is unnamed, it is equivalent." Should "is" be "if"? And what's an unnamed scope? I think the question is about enums in C++ and not C, and that correcting "namespace" to "scope" was an error.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the sense in which an enum is ever equivalent to a series of `#define` statements. The question has lots of upvotes, but it contains fundamentally wrong assumptions.

Comment: @Anonymous: I don't think it's a C++ question.  C++'s stronger typing makes it a bit more straightforward, whereas in C it's not as obvious how using the `enum` type is different from using a plain `int`. (Anyway, the OP made the "namespace" => "scope" adjustment himself, so I presume he knows what he's asking.) I do totally agree that the supposed equivalence of `enum` constants to preprocessor macros is a misconception.

Comment: @Anonymous, now I understand what you meant. You should have edited my question, to avoid spreading confusion to newcomers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `enum` type conveys intent.

Suppose you have a function that takes an `enum` constant as an argument.

```
void foo(enum MyType_e e);
```

is self-documenting about what valid inputs are but:

```
void foo(int e);
```

is not.  Moreover, the compiler may issue warnings if you attempt to pass incompatible values for the `enum` type.  From Annex I ("Common warnings") of the ISO C99 specification:

> An implementation may generate warnings in many situations.... The following are a few of the more common situations.
>
> [...]
>
> - A value is given to an object of an enumeration type other than by assignment of an enumeration constant that is a member of that type, or an enumeration variable that has the same type, or the value of a function that returns the same enumeration type (6.7.2.2).

Some compilers (for example, gcc) might even generate warnings if you use `switch` on an `enum` type but neglect to handle all of its constants and don't have a `default` case.

Comment: I don't like cluttering answers with useless comments but this is really a great answer and I had no idea you could do this. As a matter of interest though, how would the compiler "issue warnings if you attempt to pass incompatible values for the enum type.". Surely this would only be known at runtime outside of the compilers view?

Comment: @DeanP When I wrote "the compiler may issue warnings if you attempt to pass incompatible values for the `enum` type", I meant values that can be statically determined to be invalid for the `enum`.  For example, if you have `enum MyEnum { a, b, c }; void foo(enum MyEnum e);` and try to invoke it with `foo(100)`, that's clearly wrong, and you wouldn't get any compile-time warning if the function were declared with an `int` parameter instead.

Answer (score 3):

While you can perfectly say

```
int var = A
```

the variant

```
enum mytype var = A
```

is better for documentatory reasons.

Comment: How about assigning 1 to `var` that's declared `enum mytype var` or passing 1 when the function's parameter is of type `enum mytype`?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Nothing prevents you from doing so.

Comment: You could get at least a useful warning.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are good and correct, I just want to add that certain debuggers, are able to show the enum name when hovering or mointoring an enum type variable. This really helps clarity, especially when enums are used for states in state machine implementation.