# Are enum values resolved in preprocess time or in compile time?

Tags: c, c11

When are enum values resolved? In other words, is the following code snippet standard-compliant?

```
enum{
    A,
    B,
    MAX
}

#if MAX > 42
#    error "Woah! MAX is a lot!"
#endif
```

Comment: enums have nothing to do with the preprocessor.

Comment: @Michael Burr, The above code actually compiles without warnings in MSVC6.0. That is C89 - like.

Comment: I guess it does not compile with a double `u` in enum!

Comment: So what if it compiles? MAX has a value of 0. This is a very low quality question.

Comment: @JimBalter MAX has a value of 2 here.

Comment: @DidierTrosset Not to the preprocessor. MAX has a value of 0 in the #if. Learn something about the C language before commenting, please.

Comment: @DidierTrosset BTW, this is a classic case of inept testing. If either you or the OP had tried `#if MAX == 2` instead of `#if MAX > 42` you would have learned something. That's why I used the form I did in my answer (which I note that you didn't bother to read before commenting, nor did you read Michael's answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The preprocessor doesn't have anything to do with enums. But your example compiles without error, so what's going on with the `#if MAX > 42` directive?

Whenever the preprocessor is handling a conditional directive, any identifiers that are not defined as macros are treated as 0.  So assuming that `MAX` isn't defined elsewhere as a macro, your snippet of code is equivalent to:

```
enum{
    A,
    B,
    MAX
}

#if 0 > 42
#    error "Woah! MAX is a lot!"
#endif
```

From C99 6.10.1/3 "Conditional inclusion":

> ... After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined
>   unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers are
>   replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is
>   converted into a token. ...

The same wording is in the C89/C90 standard.

Comment: Such a silly mistake from my part! Thank you all for clearing this up.